# Dropping cassandra keyspaces using java processbuilder

Tags: java, windows, bash, cassandra

I have a cleanup shell script which  is intended to drop all cassandra keyspaces except system keyspaces. I am able to execute the shell script using java processbuilder, but my script pointing to wrong location of cqlsh.py (Adding D: drive letter automatically)

Note- My project workspace is located in D: drive of window OS

cleanup.sh file --

```
 #!/bin/bash
 hostname=$1

 echo "---------------------------"
 echo "   Clearing Cassandra with keyspaces"
 echo "---------------------------"

 echo -e "\nGet a list of all keyspaces that doesn't contain system prefix"
 keyspaces=$(echo desc keyspaces | cqlsh $hostname | xargs -n1 echo | grep -v ^system)

 echo -e "\nDropping all keyspaces that doesn't contain system prefix..."
 for ks in $keyspaces; do
    echo "drop keyspace $ks;" | cqlsh $hostname
    #echo Dropped "$ks"
 done
 echo -e "DONE"
 sleep 2
```

This is the java class in my project which is executing the shell file-

```
URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("cleanup.sh");
File resourceFile = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
String resourceFilePath = resourceFile.getAbsolutePath();

String cmd[] = {"sh", resourceFilePath,"127.0.0.1"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);

Process proc = pb.start();
```

But when I execute the java program I get following error -

```
---------------------------
   Clearing Cassandra with keyspaces
---------------------------

Get a list of all keyspaces that doesn't contain system prefix
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\c\Users\Dell\tools\apache-cassandra-2.2.6\bin/cqlsh.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Dropping all keyspaces that doesn't contain system prefix...
DONE
```

As you can see it says can't open file 'D:\c\Users\Dell\tools\apache-cassandra-2.2.6\bin/cqlsh.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory, if you notice the file path starting with D: drive, I guess it is because my project workpspace is running in D: drive. So how do I get it work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the `cqlsh` it would be easier & more portable to do it via Cassandra Java driver - just get a [list of keyspaces](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/Metadata.html#getKeyspaces--) from `Metadata` class, and drop all non-system (if you're using DSE, be careful because there are system keyspaces with name like `dse_...`).  The code could look like following (not tested):

```
Metadata md = cluster.getMetadata();
List<KeyspaceMetadata> keyspaces = md.getKeyspaces();
for (KeyspaceMetadata ks: keyspaces) {
   if (ks.getName().startsWith("system"))
      continue;
   session.execute("drop keyspace " + ks.getName());
}
```

Comment: thank for the answer. Yes I know that is the way around to have the code of shell scripts converted to Java code to make this work. But I have other lots of shell scripts which all deals with some logic to interact with cassandra and basically I am looking to go for the script way to do so.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what kind of scripts do you need to run via `cqlsh` that isn't possible to do from the Java driver directly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this : `"D:\c\Users\Dell\tools\apache-cassandra-2.2.6\bin\cqlsh.py"` or `"D:\\c\\Users\\Dell\\tools\\apache-cassandra-2.2.6\\bin\\cqlsh.py"` instead of : `"D:\c\Users\Dell\tools\apache-cassandra-2.2.6\bin/cqlsh.py"`. You have a slash and not a backslash in your expression.